# BigQuery - REGEXP_CONTAINS removes NULL value

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to exclude rows where website contain xyz and 123. However the query is also excluding rows with NULL value. So instead of 4 rows, it returns 3 rows i.e. number 6 is excluded.

Can someone tell what is causing the problem and the correct solution?

I don't want to use NOT IN since my exclusion criteria is a long list, so I think REGEXP_CONTAINS is the only way out. If there's any other string function, then please suggest.

**Query Used:**

```
SELECT number,source,detail,website FROM `tablename` where not REGEXP_CONTAINS(website, r'xyz') and not REGEXP_CONTAINS(website, r'123')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BigQuery`'s `regexp_contains` function when applied to `NULL` values returns `NULL`. In your case, when you apply `AND` and `NOT` operations to a `NULL` value, the value is not changed. Despite that, the `WHERE` clause sees a `NULL` value as false.

If you want to keep the false value, you should do:

```
SELECT number,source,detail,website FROM `tablename` where (not REGEXP_CONTAINS(website, r'xyz') and not REGEXP_CONTAINS(website, r'123')) or website is NULL
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It's expected to exclude `NULL`.

If you want `NULL` rows you need to add an `OR` LOGIC `columns is null`.